# Composer not auto-loading package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, steam-condenser

I'm currently working on Laravel 4.  I have added the following to my composer.json, and ran the update:

```
    "require": {
        ...
        "koraktor/steam-condenser": "*"
```

The package: https://packagist.org/packages/koraktor/steam-condenser

The issue I'm having is that if I call one of the classes it uses, for example:

```
$steamUser = new SteamId('000000000000000000');
echo "Welcome, " . $steamUser->getNickname() . "<br />";
```

I get the error `Class 'SteamId' not found`

If I manually require the file needed, then it works perfectly:

```
require_once('/home/path-to-laravel/laravel/vendor/koraktor/steam-condenser/lib/steam-condenser.php');
```

I've ran `composer dump-autoload` and still doesn't work.  Does anyone know why this is? It's really frustrating me :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Steam Condenser is not (yet) compliant to PSR-0, so you have to use a different autoloading approach (see http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload).

Using the `files` method should be best suited here:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["vendor/koraktor/steam-condenser/lib/steam-condenser.php"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Koraktor it's working! Thanks very much for taking the time to look into it.

Comment: Actually, `classmap` might be a better solution. `files`  simply forces the file to be loaded, even if you do not use the classes in there. `classmap` on the other hand enables the autoloader to find the classes and only load them on demand.

Comment: Hm, looking at it it seems like `files` is indeed the right choice. The file you're loading not just loads the classes but contains some data needed by them as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just requiring a package, does not force composer to autoload the package.

Have a look into autoloading with composer, but something like these should get you started:

```
autoload: {
    "classmap": ["vendor/koraktor/steam-condenso/lib"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks (there is a typo in that though).  I'm confused though, other packages I've been using (such as HybridAuth) literally worked out of the box, didn't have to add anything, but with this I did?  It does load the files. However I get the error "Use of undefined constant STEAM_CONDENSER_PATH - assumed 'STEAM_CONDENSER_PATH' - I guess that's because it isn't loading a file which is defining that.

Comment: Have a look into the code and see where this define happens and figure out if it is getting loaded.

Comment: Happens in the "steam-condenser.php" file: define('STEAM_CONDENSER_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/'); So I assume not... but it is within the /lib/ directory which is odd!